# How can I relate a google user with a document in my collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

I have an Express and Mongo blog app.
I implemented the google authentication, but I don't know how to save the user id along with the post that the user creates.

This are the google settings:

```
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
const googleVerify = async( idToken = '' ) => {

    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
        idToken,
        audience: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    });
  
    const { name, 
            picture: img, 
            email,
            sub: id
    } = ticket.getPayload();

    return { name, img, email, id };
  
}


const googleSignIn = async(req, res = response) => {

    try {
        let googleUser = await googleVerify(req.body.id_token);
        console.log(googleUser);
        // console.log(googleUser);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({
            msg: 'Token de google no valido'
        })
    }

}
```

And this is the post route for an article:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;

    const article = new Article({
        title: body.title,
        description: body.description,
        markdown: body.markdown,
        img: req.file.filename
    });

    try {
        await article.save();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.render('new', {article: article});
    } finally {
        res.redirect(`/articles/${article.id}`);
    }

});
```

How can I access the logged user from that article route?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

One way to get get your logged-in user from your express post route would be to call your `googleVerify()` function from within the route like this

```js
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    ...

    const googleUser = await googleVerify(req.body.id_token);
    // Do stuff with your googleUser here

    ...
});
```

The above should work just fine, provided the client is sending the `id_token` during the post request, and if your `googleVerify()` function is defined in another file then you might need to export and import it here to use.

Another way would be to use the `googleSignIn` function as a middleware

```js
router.post('/', googleSignIn, upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    ...
    let body = req.body;
    // you should have access to googleUser like this
    // body.googleUser
    ...
});
```

Then refactor your `googleSignIn` function to take a `next` function like this

```js
const googleSignIn = async(req, res, next) => {

    try {
        let googleUser = await googleVerify(req.body.id_token);
        console.log(googleUser);

        req.body.googleUser = googleUser; // set user to the request body
        next(); // Moves to next middleware

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({
            msg: 'Token de google no valido'
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried do it both ways, but I don't know why I get the error of invalid token.

Comment: That is because your client isn't sending an `id_token`. Try passing the `id_token` in the body when you're making the request to post an article.